# Сложение(+) в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, при скрипте:

```
function pl(){
//document.getElementById('inp2').value
alert(document.getElementById('inp2').value+document.getElementById('inp2').value);
}
```

Если `value=12`,  выдает `1212..` Что и как нужно сделать, чтобы получилось `24`?

Comment: В числа переведите оба значения и складывайте, например

Comment: Используйте - > parseInt(string, radix);

Comment: Значения любого `input` `js` принимает как `string`, если ваши значения цифрового типа то нужно преобразовать их явно методами `parseInt`, `parseFloat`, смотря какие значения у вас в полях. подробно об этом можете прочитать здесь `http://javascript.ru/parseint`, `http://javascript.ru/parsefloat`.

Answer (score 2):

Аттрибуты являются строками и оператор `+` является для них операцией конкатенации.
Для сложения строк как чисел, нужно явно распарсить строку в число.

Например функция `parseInt`:

`alert(parseInt(document.getElementById('inp2').value)+parseInt(document.getElementById('inp2').value));`

Еще есть вариант через унарный оператор `+`:

`var test1 = +document.getElementById('inp2').value;
alert(test1+test1)`

На [learn.javascript.ru](https://learn.javascript.ru/types-conversion) можно прочитать подробней про преобразования.

**UPDATE**

Есть особенность работы `parseInt`: в разных браузерах строки, которые начинаются с 0 ( например '010') могут преобразоваться либо в восмеричную( в примере получится 8), либо в десятичную систему счисления. [Описание на mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

По спецификации ecmascript 5 по умолчанию явно задаётся десятичная система счисления, т.е. `parseInt('010') -> 10`

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: `parseInt('0xf')` даст `15`, так что лучше дописывать `10` вторым параметром

Comment: Если значение не попадает под паттерн `0x...` или `0...`, то парсится в десятичную систему счисления

Comment: Обязательно найдётся пользователь, который введёт число с нулём в начале и в результате получит совсем не то что ожидал

Comment: @TatevikKhachatryan галочка слева - щёлк :)

Comment: @andreymal, 0 давно не делает число восьмеричным.

Comment: @Qwertiy , пожалуйста прикладывай ссылки на спецификации. Да, начиная ecma5, по умолчанию идёт десятичная система, но тот же mdn рекомендует явно указывать второй параметр

Answer (score 1):

`value` у `input`а содержит строку. А сложение превращается в конкатенацию если хотя бы один из аргументов - строка. Чтобы привести строку к числу надо использовать унарный плюс.

```js
var s = "12", x = 12;

console.log(JSON.stringify(s + s));   // "1212"
console.log(JSON.stringify(s + x));   // "1212"
console.log(JSON.stringify(x + s));   // "1212"
console.log(JSON.stringify(x + x));   // 24

var y = +s;

console.log(JSON.stringify(y + y));   // 24
```

Comment: Зачем переводить в json постоянно?

Comment: @НазарКалитюк попробуйте без него

Comment: @НазарКалитюк, для вывода на консоль, чтобы строки в кавычках оказались, а то во встроенной консоли (в отличие от настоящей браузерной) число от строки не отличишь.

Answer (score 1):

используйте `parseInt(строкаВвидеЧисла)`

```js
function pl(){
 if(document.getElementById('inp2').value == "") {
alert("0");
}
else {
alert(parseInt(document.getElementById('inp2').value)+parseInt(document.getElementById('inp2').value));

}

}
```

```html
<input id="inp2" type="number" required>
<button onclick="pl()">Сложить</button>
```